# Creating a VSTS Extension, using WIQL query to grab work item data, can I grab Activity field data?

Tags: wiql, azure-devops-rest-api

I'm creating a Visual Studio Team Services extension that in it's current iteration is supposed to display child tasks for development, testing, etc. that were added to a work item. I build a WIQL query to get these tasks and some data about them.

In VSTS (and TFS), tasks have an Activity field, which I want, to differentiate between the different types of tasks (development, testing, etc.). However, I'm finding with the below WIQL query I create, I get the following error: **TF51005: The query references a field that does not exist. The error is caused by «[System.Activity]».** Is there a way I can get access to the Activity field for those tasks? Or is it just not supported currently?

```
SELECT [System.Id], [System.WorkItemType], [System.Title], 
       [System.Activity], [System.State] 
FROM WorkItemLinks 
WHERE (Source.[System.TeamProject] = 'someProjectID' 
    AND Source.[System.Id] = someWorkItemID
    AND Source.[System.State] <> 'Removed') 
    AND ([System.Links.LinkType] = 'System.LinkTypes.Hierarchy-Forward') 
    AND (Target.[System.WorkItemType] = 'Task') 
MODE(Recursive)
```

Working through this I discovered https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ottostreifel.wiql-editor, which has helped make it alot easier debugging my WIQL query. I highly recommend it to anyone who is new to working with WIQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked some more and discovered my answer, apparently **Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Activity** is the field you want to reference to get the activity for the task. I found it here: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/query-numeric. Looks like there's some more information there about some data you can grab, like **Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.StoryPoints**. However it's definitely not a complete list, and I wasn't able to find one. Feel free to comment on this if you know of a complete list of references to use to grab anything you want about a work item!

Comment: Hi,
     Microsoft has exposed REST Endpoints to get all the information about fields that exists in your account. Please use the URL "https://<Your VSTS Name>.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection/_apis/wit/fields?api-version=1.0"     in postman / fiddler with authentication to get list of fields and their reference names.

P.S to authenticate create "Alternate Credentials" or "Personal Access Tokens" in your VSTS account. See this link to know how to create Alternate Credentials / Personal Token  "https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/auth-overview"


Hope this Helps!! :)

Comment: To know more about VSTS API's refer here : https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/overview

Comment: Thank you! I'm sure this will become useful in the future :)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a query with necessary fields in web access, then get detail wiql by using [Get a query or folder](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/queries#get-a-query-or-folder) REST API (add **$expand=wiql** parameter).